# Delete rows from several tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I use these tables to store data.
I would like to delete all data older than 1 month (for example) using one SQL query from all tables.

```
-- TABLE AGENT_HISTORY

CREATE TABLE AGENT_HISTORY(
  EVENT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  AGENTID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  EVENT_DATE DATE NOT NULL
)
/

CREATE TABLE CPU_HISTORY(
  CPU_HISTORY_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  EVENT_ID INTEGER,
  CPU_NAME VARCHAR2(50 ) NOT NULL,
  CPU_VALUE NUMBER NOT NULL
)
/

CREATE TABLE CPU_TEMP_HISTORY(
  CPU_TEMP_HISTORY_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  EVENT_ID INTEGER,
  CPU_TEMP_NAME VARCHAR2(50 ) NOT NULL,
  CPU_TEMP_VALUE NUMBER NOT NULL
)
/

CREATE TABLE MEMORY_HISTORY(
  MEMORY_HISTORY_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  EVENT_ID INTEGER,
  MEMORY_NAME VARCHAR2(50 ) NOT NULL,
  MEMORY_VALUE NUMBER NOT NULL
)
/

CREATE TABLE DISK_HISTORY(
  DISK_HISTORY_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  EVENT_ID INTEGER,
  DISK_NAME VARCHAR2(50 ) NOT NULL,
  DISK_VALUE NUMBER NOT NULL
)
/

CREATE TABLE NETWORK_HISTORY(
  NETWORK_HISTORY_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  EVENT_ID INTEGER,
  ADAPTER_NAME VARCHAR2(50 ) NOT NULL,
  TRANSMITBYTES NUMBER NOT NULL,
  TRANSMITSPEED NUMBER,
  RECEIVESPEED NUMBER,
  RECEIVEBYTES NUMBER
)
/

CREATE TABLE SWAP_HISTORY(
  SWAP_HISTORY_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  EVENT_ID INTEGER,
  SWAP_NAME VARCHAR2(50 ) NOT NULL,
  SWAP_VALUE NUMBER NOT NULL
)
/

CREATE TABLE CONNECTIONS_HISTORY(
  CONNECTIONS_HISTORY_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  EVENT_ID INTEGER,
  CONNECTIONS_NAME VARCHAR2(50 ) NOT NULL,
  CONNECTIONS_VALUE NUMBER NOT NULL
)
/

CREATE TABLE PARTITIONS_HISTORY(
  PARTITIONS_HISTORY_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  EVENT_ID INTEGER,
  PARTITIONS_NAME VARCHAR2(50 ) NOT NULL,
  PARTITIONS_VALUE NUMBER NOT NULL
)
/
```

Is this possible in Oracle?
I use EVENT_ID as unique key ID in all tables.

Comment: Only one of the tables has a `date` column, so it is not clear what you intend to delete in the others.

Comment: do you mean EVENT_ID as the unique key?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Create foreign keys to the `event` table with `on delete cascade` and then delete from that table.

Comment: Can you show me example how to do it?

Comment: check if this is feasible to have one more table with EVENT_ID and Date separately. later with combination of that you can delete in all the tables

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by "a_horse_with_no_name", you can use **[ON DELETE CASCADE](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52180)** by creating the required relationships.

For example,

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name
   FOREIGN KEY (column1, column2, ... column_n)
   REFERENCES parent_table (column1, column2, ... column_n)
   ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Bookmark the [Database SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/toc.htm) and start reading the concepts for better understanding.

Comment: Can you please show me the complete example of the SQL query?